# How to delete a variable during uninstall?

Tags: configuration

I've never run into this problem before, but the variable I set in my module won't delete during uninstall. What am I doing wrong?

I set the variable in my module like this:

```
variable_set('marigold_nutrients', $nutrients);
```

All is good. The variable saves just fine and I'm able to use it as normal with `variable_get`.

Here is how I try to delete it:

In my module's `.install` file, I implement hook_uninstall...

```
/**
 * Implements hook_uninstall().
 */
function marigold_nutrition_uninstall() {
  variable_del('marigold_nutrients');
}
```

Using the UI, I remove the module then uninstall it. The database table the module creates deletes just fine, and it looks as though it's uninstalled. However, when I look at the variable table in Sequel Pro, the 'marigold_nutrients' variable is still there. I've run cron, cleared the cache... not sure what to do.

MORE INFO:
- Using the debugger, I see that when I uninstall the module, it steps into the uninstall function just fine, so I'm pretty sure that function is working.

Comment: `variable_del` is the way to go. All Drupal modules use this function. This function deletes the relevant record AND clears the cache. Make sure that you look at the correct database and your spelling is correct, that the .install file is correct, double-check everything.

Comment: I know, `variable_del` has always worked for me in the past. I've checked and double checked spelling... was up until after midnight last night trying to figure it out. I'm not sure what's wrong this time.

Comment: Can you see the `hook_uninstall()` is called at all? the variable_get/set/del are small and straight forward functions and never had any problem using them.

Comment: Does it work with a db_query instead? (Even if it is dirty)

Comment: Yes, it steps into the uninstall function just fine. I haven't tried deleting the variable manually (db_query), but `variable_del` should work. This all seems pretty straight forward. I don't have anything complicated in this module.

Comment: Is there something in the reports?

Comment: @Djouuuuh No, no errors are logged in the reports.

Comment: make sure variable_set('marigold_nutrients'); is not getting executed via any other installed module you might be missing/

Comment: The variable gets set during installation when the hook_schema calls a function to iterate through an array to create database columns. That's the only time the variable gets set. It gets called a couple times inside the module to grab the labels, machine names and unit information. Could my problem be somewhere in that the variable is set in the .install file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is probably here (from the comments):

> The variable gets set during installation when the hook_schema calls a function to iterate through an array to create database columns.

The uninstall process calls [`drupal_uninstall_schema()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_uninstall_schema/7), which in turn calls [`drupal_get_schema_unprocessed()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_get_schema_unprocessed/7), which invokes `hook_schema()`.

So the variable is being added again during uninstall, presumably at a later point in the process than your `hook_uninstall()` is invoked and `variable_del()` has run.

Comment: Yes, that sounds like the answer. Do you know if there is a way to force the `variable_del` to run at the end of the uninstall process?

Comment: There wouldn't be one in a normal workflow, you arguably shouldn't be setting a variable inside `hook_schema()` at all because its job is to _provide_ data, not manipulate it. The proper place to set the variable in the first instance would be `hook_install()`. That should run before `hook_schema()` is invoked, so you can easily pick it up from there

Comment: I definitely want to set this up correctly and use best practices, as I'm very much new to this and still learning loads every day. I've tried setting the variable in `hook_install`, but it looks like `hook_schema` has already been run and built the tables _before_ 'hook_install' is called.